# Zurb Ink issue on Outlook

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2010, zurb-ink

I'm creating an email using Zurb Ink and it's working fine on all emails. But on Outlook 2010, I found some errors. The biggest problem is that the width of the columns changes. They get bigger.

The grid does not respect the maximum width of 580px.

Comment: Did you just use an standard template from http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php? Without any code given noone can reproduce your error.

Comment: I followed the documentation. Here is my code: http://abpq.com.br/newsletter/template.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance increase the system fonts size on Windows?

If you have, outlook will distort some emails.

Try sending the email to other people with Outlook 2010 or run a litmus test to make sure that local windows settings are not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But Zurb Ink is not compatible with Outlook?

Comment: I don't know what Zurd Ink is.

Answer (score 0):

Well max and min-width don't work in Outlook. I'm not 100% on how Ink gets around this, so you could always wrap your container table in

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
<tr valign="top">
<td align="center" valign="top">
<![endif]-->
     CODE GOES HERE
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inline your code? You always want to inline your code before testing, as certain email clients won't read stylesheets in the header. Ink includes this tool on their website: http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

Ink include `float:left;` for all images.

When I include an image above a text, the float do his job.

What I do is include a `float:none!important;`on this images.